# iPhone 4 display issue with Google map in object tag

Tags: iphone, html, css, mobile-safari

I am embedding a Google map into an html page using the `<object>` tag. The map is displayed inside of a set of tabs.  It works fine in all major desktop browsers, android phones, and the iPhone simulator. However, it's displaying incorrectly on an iPhone 4.

http://rjthieneman.com/property/northcrest-plaza/

If you view it on an iPhone 4 or iPad, the map will not stay inside the tabs, instead it will display in the top left corner of the screen and cover the page.

Any help would be appreciated.

#### Update

I ended up using an `<iframe>` and it seems to work. I'd prefer to use the `<object>` tag though

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! You should post your "update" as an answer and then select it, so that users who find this in the future will see the answer, in case they re looking for help with this issue.

Answer (score 0):

Go back to using an object, and then try this CSS:

```
#aerial {
   height: 415px;
   width: 936px;
   overflow: hidden;
   position: relative;
}
```